# flex datechooser can't select first "selectable" date

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Problem: I'm using the selectableRange property of a DateChooser, but the DateChooser will not allow me to "select" the first date within the selectableRange.

Here is the code. Give it a go.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:comps="comps.*"
    backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF"
    layout="vertical" xmlns:text="flash.text.*">

    <mx:DateFormatter id="df"/>

    <mx:DateChooser id="dc" allowMultipleSelection="true" selectableRange="{{rangeStart : new Date(2010,0,1), rangeEnd : new Date(2010,7,31)}}"/>

    <mx:TextArea id="ta" text="{df.format(dc.selectedRanges[0].rangeStart) + ' to ' + df.format(dc.selectedRanges[0].rangeEnd)}"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Try selecting Jan 1 - Jan 10 using Shift-click. No go. But try selecting Jan 2 - Jan 11, works fine. What's up with Jan 1?

You can also find the app here: http://www.flexdevelopers.com/examples/dateChooser/bug1/SampleApp.html

Comment: I played around with your sample and my best suggestion is to file a bug at bugs.adobe.com .

Comment: It appears that this bug - https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-13894 - represents the problem. It has been open since 2007 (nice Adobe). Anyhow, the last comment seems to be a solution ("I've modified the file CalendarLayout.as. In the function 'public function get selectedRanges():Array', i've added a 'break' in the second case and the problem has desapeared.")....but, I'm not sure how to override a public getter that has references to private variables. :(

Comment: overriding a get method just like any other 'override public function get something():someValue'   Private variables are not directly related to overriding.  However, if you want to copy/paste code from the super method into the child method, private variables could become a big problem.  You need to recreate the private variable in the child and move all references to that private variable into your child component. It's a pain. Sometime it is easier to copy and paste the full component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with flextras, it does look like a bug.  As a workaround you might be able to get away with this:

```
<mx:DateChooser id="dc" allowMultipleSelection="true" selectableRange="{{rangeStart : new Date(2010,11,31), rangeEnd : new Date(2010,7,31)}}" disabledRanges="{[new Date(2009,11,31)]}"/>
```

Where Dec 31, 2009 is showing, but disabled.  If you wanted to go further I am sure that you could write a small function to disable the back arrow when in January 2010 to prevent the user from even going into December 2009.

Comment: I implemented this workaround. Not totally happy with it...but it seems to get the job done..for now...